# Setting a CardView's height as a custom percentage of the screen size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-layout-weight

I have a fragment that displays a RecyclerView that is populated with an Array of objects - 1 CardView for each object. I want my application to display 5 CardView's and have the 6th CardView peeking on the screen regardless of the size (by making each CardView's height set to 18% of the entire screen's height). I currently have this code to make each CardView's height set to 1/6 of the entire screen. The issue with this method is that I can only make each CardView's height 1/x of the entire screen, where x can only be an integer (I want to be able to make the height of each CardView a custom percentage of the screen's height instead of only being able to make it 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, etc. of the screen size).

```java
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Log.i(TAG, "WM     " + wm);

Point size = new Point();
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
display.getSize(size);
int heighty = size.y;
int height = heighty/6; // does not work with doubles because setLayoutParams must be (int)

Log.i(TAG, "height     " + heighty + "       " + display);
CardView cm = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.card);
Log.i(TAG, "cm     " + cm);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = cm.getLayoutParams();

Log.i(TAG, "params      params     " + params);
params.height= height;
params.width=MATCH_PARENT;
cm.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This is my xml file for each CardView that is displayed

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:cardElevation="4dp"
android:id="@+id/card"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name_iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_iv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have attempted to change this implementation to utilize a LinearLayout inside a ConstraintLayout, where the LinearLayout's height is 18% of the entire screen, and the height of the instances of the LinearLayout(ImageView and 2 textView's) are a percentage of the LinearLayout. My xml for that implementation :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/cardview_id"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.18"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name_iv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_desc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/user_name_iv"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/user_iv"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This makes each instance of the RecyclerView the  height I desire (18% of the screen's height), but my RecyclerView makes each individual instance designated to one screen each instead of making the instances displayed right below one another (I know this is because the ConstraintLayout's height is match_parent, but wrap_content makes the content disappear). I would like to know if there is an ideal approach to accomplishing what I'm trying to do or being able to fix the issue above.

My RecyclerView xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/nestedView"
android:fillViewport="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. For anyone that has this issue and would like the answer, I modified the Java code above to make each cardView's height any fraction of the screen's height.

```java
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Log.i(TAG, "WM     " + wm);

        Point size = new Point();
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        display.getSize(size);
        int heighty = size.y;
        double heightDouble = heighty/2.5; // this will make the screen display 2 cardview's and have half of the third one peeking. replace 2.5 with any decimal you desire to make your last cardview peek a certain amount
        int height = (int) Math.rint(heightDouble); 



        Log.i(TAG, "height     " + heighty + "       " + display);
        CardView cm = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.card);
        Log.i(TAG, "cm     " + cm);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = cm.getLayoutParams();

        Log.i(TAG, "params      params     " + params);
        params.height= height;
        params.width=MATCH_PARENT;
        cm.setLayoutParams(params);
```