# Setting a CardView's height as a custom percentage of the screen size in the XML layout file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

I have a simple CardView that just contains an ImageView inside and I would like to know if it is possible to set the height as a percentage of the whole screen in the XML layout file such that it would scale for different screen sizes? Here ([Setting a CardView's height as a custom percentage of the screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409633/setting-a-cardviews-height-as-a-custom-percentage-of-the-screen-size)) it is shown how to do this programatically but I am wondering if this is also possible by just editing the XML layout file as I think this is more convenient and you have a better overview over the layout.

Here is the XML layout file of the Cardview (currently with a hardcoded height)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"

    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPadding="0dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="0dp"
    app:contentPaddingLeft="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>




        </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: _ConstraintLayout_ does not accommodate setting a view's size based upon the total screen size just in XML. If you are using data binding, you could set the size based on the screen's size in XML using an adapter but that would still require some backing code.

Comment: @Cheticamp: Thanks Cheticamp for your answer. Well actually ConstraintLayout does allow to set the view's size as a percentage of the sceen. I have used this many times e.g. by adding `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.21"`. But unfortunately I can't use it in the CardView Layout as a whole. I can just use it inside the CardView but not for the CardView itself. And my question is whether there is a way to set the size of the whole CardView as a percentage of the screen because otherwise the layout is not device independant and does not scale.

Comment: `layout_constraintWidth_percent` specifies the percentage width of the containing _ConstraintLayout_. What you state only applies if the width of the _ConstraintLayout_ is equal to the width of the screen. In any case, what I stated in my first comments still holds whether the _CardView_ stands alone are is part of another _ViewGroup_.

Comment: @Cheticamp: Thanks for your answer Cheticamp. What would you advice me to do if I want to have device independant Cardviews that scale with the size of the screen? Unfortunately, using dp is a bad choice if you really want device independant Cardviews because the Cardview will not scale.

Comment: If the _CardView_ stands on its own (not within a _ViewGroup_ that you have defined), I suggest placing it into a _ConstraintLayout_ that fills the screen and use _layout_constraintHeight_percent_ to size the _CardView_. If within a _ViewGroup_ that you have defined, I suggest you change the group to a _ConstraintLayout_ (if not already one) and do the above.

Comment: @Cheticamp: Thanks Cheticamp for your answer and effort. I really appreciate it. How can I make the CardView stand on its own? As far as I see it, I did not explicity define a ViewGroup around it (at least the word ViewGroup is not used in my code). How can I include a ConstraintLayout to the CardView as a whole?

Comment: @Cheticamp: Thanks Cheticamps for your answer. Any comments on my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: You'11 have to use some code if you can't wrap the _CardView_ with a _ConstraintLayout_.

Comment: @Cheticamp: Thanks for your comment. I'd like to wrap the CardView with a ConstraintLayout. How can I do this in the XML layout file?

Comment: It would help if you can post your XML layout file.

Comment: @Cheticamp: Thanks Cheticamp for your comment. Actually, I have already posted my XML layout file when setting up the question. Just have a look at the question and at the very bottom you can see the XML layout file of the Cardview (currently with a hardcoded height)

Comment: I don't think that I am understanding your issue, but this may help: Take a look at [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXM0p.png). It shows how to place a _CarView_ in a _ConstraintLayout_. You would just need to specify _layout_constraintHeight_percent_. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#match_constraint-dimensions-added-in-1.1).

Comment: @Cheticamp: Thanks Cheticamp for your answer. So actually what I want is to set the whole CardView's size as a percentage of the whole screen. When you look at my code I define the height of the CardView  by using `android:layout_height="140dp"`. Using 140dp makes the CardView not scale when a bigger device is used. I would like the size of the CardView to be let's say 10 % of the device's height all the time no matter which device is used. Is there a way how I can do that?

Comment: If my last comment doesn't work for you then you will have to do it programmatically AFAIK.